# Thunderbird replies using qmail extensions

Tags: thunderbird, qmail

I make generous use of qmail extensions (e.g., user-extension@domain.com). These extensions are not used by qmail for mail delivery — all mail goes to the user@domain.com mailbox. However, the extension is still present in the To: address.

When replying to such mail, I would like the From: address to echo that original To: address. Thunderbird allows me to override the From address, but I need to remember to do that — not a good bet.

Is there a way for Thunderbird to automatically use the To address in the response rather than the address configured for the user at setup?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only feature that may reduce your effort, are identities (http://mzl.la/1BsOxfw) if you only have a few qmail extensions (at least you can choose from a dropdown menu instead of typing the e-mail address every time, plus you can automatically sort these emails accordingly then if you like).

Comment: Thanks Tim P for the idea. I had seen “Identities” and discounted them because I use extensions ALOT. It would not be practical to create individual identities. I feel like I really need to tap the “To:” address in the header, turning it around to send the replies. I’m starting to look at creating an add-on (no existing ones seem to do what I want), though I’m running into trouble with those. Probably more stackoverflow questions to come...